# Gnuplot parametric and data?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file with some `x, y` data in a file and I want to plot it as well as a parametric function that the should follow in the same graph.

How could I do it?

Comment: Do you mean fitting some data? Please give a minimal example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parametric plot can always be restructured to use an explicit sampling of the control variable `t`, indicated by the pseudo-filename '+'.

parametric:

```
plot A(t), B(t)
```

sampled:

```
plot '+' using (A($1)):(B($1))
```

You can easily mix this with data plots.  The range of the sampled control variable `t` need not be the same as the `x` range of the data plot.

```
plot 'file1.dat' with points, [t=0:2*pi] '+' using (A($1)):(B($1)) with lines
```